# No networking for Centos under VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

Running an Ubuntu desktop server. I installed virtual box, then installed CentOS as a virtual machine. Centos is not starting the eth0 network adaptor. When I start it manually, I cannot connect outside the machine.

Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Virtual Box 4.1.12 and CentOS 6.2 and Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit. Using NAT addressing.

Networking for the Main Server:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:12:a7:9a  
          inet addr:10.0.0.99  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca60:ff:fe12:a79a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15492 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3083151 (3.0 MB)  TX bytes:1104784 (1.1 MB)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:789448 (789.4 KB)  TX bytes:789448 (789.4 KB)
```

Networking for the CentOS virtual Server:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:75:b2:9ac2
          inet addr:10.0.0.98  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe75:b2c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:1350 (1.3 KiB)


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:789448 (789.4 KB)  TX bytes:789448 (789.4 KB)
```

Comment: Post `ifconfig -a` from guest and tell us what type of networking you have enabled in VM settings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with this appears to have been the NAT setting. It requires you to use 10.0.2.* addresses.

> To change the default network go to VirtualBox Manager's preferences and click on the Network tab. Click on the edit icon and modify the Network CIDR to the network you need for your guests. If you need to enable/disable either DHCP and/or IPv6 as well, go ahead and toggle the check boxes to your needs.

Also, when I thought about, NAT doesn't provide me with external access to that IP address. I changed it to bridged and everything now appears to be working.

Thanks for the help.